# # is converting passed function to a string and not a javascript expression in Karate

Tags: karate

- def uuid = '#(util.uuid())'
- print uuid

Printing gives me the string #(util.uuid()) back and not the generated uuid. What can be the solution?

Comment: Works for me. Follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue